# Application which can generate online treasure hunts (or, progressive Q&A)

Tags: web-apps, automation, competition, survey

I am looking for an application that can generate treasure hunts (basically which include just Q&A levels) which can be easily deployed online.

Here are the some of the important features:

- The hunt involves users progressing from *Level 1* to *Level x*, where the user is asked a specific question or posed with a certain challenge in each level, both of which involves a **specific answer**.
- The user progresses from one level to another only after the user has correctly answered the question (**retries allowed**).
- There is a public **leaderboard** which lists the users based on the level of the users and the time of answering (first to answer goes first).
- An option for the users to **login via social accounts** (Facebook, Google+, etc) would be preferable.
- The user interface involves just the current level (without the ability to go back or forth) and position of the user in the leaderboard.
- It would be useful if the **ability to edit the source of specific levels** (to include clues in the source code) is available.

If all of the above is not possible, any suggestions involving that can implement atleast the basic Q&A idea would be appreciated.

Or, **if you have a different approach (along with a tool that can implement it) for holding such a competition, it would be more than welcome.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I couldn't find a proper application which can automate the task of generating the treasure hunt template, here's something which can help you get started with a treasure hunt of your own with little to no work.

The students of NIT Calicut, India, who built a treasure hunt ([Clueless - Tathva 2013](https://github.com/xaneem/Treasure-Hunt/)) as a part of their annual inter-college fest have made the code public under GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 2.

> A fully functional online treasure hunt built in CodeIgniter, for
>   Clueless 2013, conducted as a part of Tathva, at NIT Calicut, India.

The setup seems to satisfy almost all the requirements mentioned above. The only problem for a beginner might face might be setting up everything in the server. But, they also have a guide to help you set it up.